# Proof involving an $\iff$ statement related to eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following theoreom:

> Let us consider the matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$. $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ iff $(\lambda I - A)$ is not invertible, or, equivalently, $\det (\lambda I - A) = 0$.

I managed to prove the part $\Rightarrow$, but not the other way around, i.e. given that $\lambda I - A$ is not invertible, we need to show that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Could you please help me to show it?

Comment: If $\lambda I-A$ is not invertible, its null space is non trivial. So let $v\ne0$ belong to the null space…

Answer (score 1):

If it's not invertible, it means there is a vector $ v \not = 0$ such that: $(\lambda I - A)v = 0$, then rearranging you immediately get that $v$ is an eigenvector.

How do we know there is such vector $v$?
 Let the matrix $M$ to non-invertible. That means there are at least two vectors $u$ and $v$, with $u \not = v$ that get mapped to the same vector: $Mu = Mv$ (what should $M^{-1}Mu$ be?). Then using the properties of linear algebra: $Mu - Mv = M(u-v) = 0$. This vector $u-v \not = 0$ is the vector we were looking for.